# Changing hover style for QComboBox

Tags: css, qt

I am using Qt 5.1.1
I am trying to change the background color and text color for an element when the cursor is on that element. I have tried the following style sheet:

```
QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item:hover {color: black;background: white }
```

But this and too many tried CSS code hasn't worked. What is the correct way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
QComboBox QAbstractItemView
{
  selection-color: red;
  selection-background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid widget background-color effect:

```
QComboBox{ background-color: white; }
QComboBox QAbstractItemView
{
 background-color: white;
 selection-color: blue;
 selection-background-color: gray; // useless
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Qt 6.4.3 and the accepted solution did not work for me, but I fixed it by doing:

```
QComboBox
{
  selection-color: red;
  selection-background-color: blue;
}
```